# why dropdownlistfor() not shown on VS 2013?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

Is there any reason why VS 2013 does not show any kind `..For()` helper methods?
e.g: `@Html.DisplayFor()`, `@Html.DropDownListFor()`...etc

Comment: are you using model for you view?

Comment: do you get other helper methods, for example '@Html.Display()', or '@Html.TextBox', etc.